# Nginx location allow ip not working as expected

Tags: nginx

i need your help with setting location allow,

```
location /route {
    deny [my-ip];
}
```

So this works, it doesn't let me access the route

Throws this error

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

And this...

```
location /route {
    allow [my-ip];
    deny all;
}
```

Doesn't let me access but it's supposed to let me access the route, can't understand why, it shows this error

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Config file (with two examples on routes):

```
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name [my-domain];

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

# Phpmyadmin Configurations
location /phpmyadmin {
   root /usr/share/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           root /usr/share/;
           #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
           #fastcgi_param HTTPS on; # <-- add this line
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
   }
   location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.
(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
           root /usr/share/;
   }
}

# Dealing with the uppercased letters
location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}

location /logs {
    deny [myip];
}

location /admin {
    allow [myip];
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't allow you access the route"?

Comment: It shows this                404 Not Found

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: can you share a more detail conf file?

Comment: @JunbangHuang there it is

Answer (score 2):

for anybody else who is searching for the solution. This did it for me after long try and error:

```
location = /phpmyadmin/index.php { 
allow 1.2.3.4;
deny all;
....
}
```

Make sure you use the  "=" sign or else it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is not the allow and deny. It is `root /usr/share/;` Since you have placed it into a location block `location /phpmyadmin`, it can not be found by `location \admin` therefore, it returns 404. Try to place the `root /usr/share/` to the server block instead of a location block.